# InsertHistoryOperation throws InvalidOperationException while no Database is existing

Tags: entity-framework

i have big Trouble using the EntityFramework 5.0. After updating EF in our Project from EF4.2 to EF5.0. The Framework throws InvalidOperationExceptions in the TypeInitializer of InsertHistoryOperation during initializing of the database. (In the InnerException it says: "The List does not contain any element").

I tried using DropCreateAlwaysInitializer as well as DropWhenModelChanges. We don't need the Migration Feature (Sure, would be nice to have, but not recommend). Is there a way to disable the Migration Feature so the exception is not thrown. Or can somebody give me a hint what i did wrong?

The Model is very complex, so i think its not very useful to post it here.

best regards,
Chris

I tried with .Net4.0 and .Net4.5

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it.

The Problem is that the EntityFramework since V5.0 is not able to work correctly if you merge it into (e.g. a Datalayer Assembly) or use it from a merged assembly. (ILMerge).